# Make sume of specific value of 2d arrays

Tags: python, iteration, 2d

```
['Less than $40K' '0.569']
['$60K - $80K' '0']
['Less than $40K' '0.3']
['$80K - $120K' '0.045']
['Unknown' '0.091']
['$40K - $60K' '0']
['$80K - $120K' '0.056']
['$60K - $80K' '0']
['Less than $40K' '0.595']
['$120K +' '0.097']
['$80K - $120K' '0.066']
['$60K - $80K' '0.216']
['$120K +' '0.031']
['Less than $40K' '0.316']
['Less than $40K' '0.045']
['$60K - $80K' '0.065']
['$80K - $120K' '0.051']
['Less than $40K' '0.342']
['$80K - $120K' '0.041']
['Unknown' '0']
['$40K - $60K' '0']
['$40K - $60K' '0']
['Less than $40K' '0']
['$80K - $120K' '0']
['Unknown' '0']
['Unknown' '0.575']
['$60K - $80K' '0.032']
['Less than $40K' '0.505']
['$120K +' '0.05']
['$80K - $120K' '0.366']
['Less than $40K' '0.182']
['Less than $40K' '0.332']
['Less than $40K' '0.194']
['$40K - $60K' '0.058']
['Less than $40K' '0.228']
['$120K +' '0.038']
['Less than $40K' '0.155']
['Less than $40K' '0.371']
['$60K - $80K' '0']
['Less than $40K' '0.258']
['$120K +' '0.036']
['$120K +' '0.148']
['$60K - $80K' '0.037']
['$120K +' '0']
['Unknown' '0']
['$60K - $80K' '0.195']
['$60K - $80K' '0']
['$40K - $60K' '0.229']
['$40K - $60K' '0.085']
['Unknown' '0']
```

I am trying to read `avgUtilArray` which is two d array and trying to find a sum for first index. So trying to add values for 'Less than $40K' and output a list, like [['Less than $40K', xx.xx], ...]

what would be the way to get a list that has sum of specific catagory?

Comment: Use a default dictionary. `d = defaultdict(float)`. Then add up each key: `for a in array2d: d[a[0]] += float(a[1])`. But you need to fix the 2d array first as it is not valid Python.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all ranges are exclusive, that is, no range overlaps another range, you could iterate over this 2D array and reduce to a `dict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = [['Less than $40K', '0.569'], ['$60K - $80K' ,'0'], ...]

res = defaultdict(float)

for tup in data:
  rng, amt = tup
  res[rng] += float(amt)

print(list(res.items()))
```

```py
[('Less than $40K', 4.3919999999999995), ('$60K - $80K', 0.545), ('$80K - $120K', 0.625), ('Unknown', 0.6659999999999999), ('$40K - $60K', 0.37200000000000005), ('$120K +', 0.4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary that uses the first column value in your avgUtilArray as key. We just check if there is a value stored for that key already, in which case, we add to it. Otherwise, we make a new entry in dictionary with that key.

```py
output = {}

for row in avgUtilArray:
    key = row[0]
    value = float(row[1])
    if key in output:
        output[key] += value
    else:
        output[key] = value

print(output)
```

The output:

```py
{'Less than $40K': 4.3919999999999995, '$60K - $80K': 0.545, '$80K - $120K': 0.625, 'Unknown': 0.6659999999999999, '$40K - $60K': 0.37200000000000005, '$120K +': 0.4}
```

Also, I corrected your 2d list for you:)

```py
avgUtilArray = [

['Less than $40K', '0.569'],
['$60K - $80K', '0'],
['Less than $40K', '0.3'],
['$80K - $120K', '0.045'],
['Unknown', '0.091'],
['$40K - $60K', '0'],
['$80K - $120K', '0.056'],
['$60K - $80K', '0'],
['Less than $40K', '0.595'],
['$120K +', '0.097'],
['$80K - $120K', '0.066'],
['$60K - $80K', '0.216'],
['$120K +', '0.031'],
['Less than $40K', '0.316'],
['Less than $40K', '0.045'],
['$60K - $80K', '0.065'],
['$80K - $120K', '0.051'],
['Less than $40K', '0.342'],
['$80K - $120K', '0.041'],
['Unknown', '0'],
['$40K - $60K', '0'],
['$40K - $60K', '0'],
['Less than $40K', '0'],
['$80K - $120K', '0'],
['Unknown', '0'],
['Unknown', '0.575'],
['$60K - $80K', '0.032'],
['Less than $40K', '0.505'],
['$120K +', '0.05'],
['$80K - $120K', '0.366'],
['Less than $40K', '0.182'],
['Less than $40K', '0.332'],
['Less than $40K', '0.194'],
['$40K - $60K', '0.058'],
['Less than $40K', '0.228'],
['$120K +', '0.038'],
['Less than $40K', '0.155'],
['Less than $40K', '0.371'],
['$60K - $80K', '0'],
['Less than $40K', '0.258'],
['$120K +', '0.036'],
['$120K +', '0.148'],
['$60K - $80K', '0.037'],
['$120K +', '0'],
['Unknown', '0'],
['$60K - $80K', '0.195'],
['$60K - $80K', '0'],
['$40K - $60K', '0.229'],
['$40K - $60K', '0.085'],
['Unknown', '0']
]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).